# How to split int each two digits and insert into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a number 112233445566

How can I split it and put it into array so that I can get

```
Array[11,22,33,44,55,66]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const num = 112233445566;
const numString = num.toString();
let numberArr = [];
let tempArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < numString.length; i++) {
  tempArr.push(numString[i]);
  if (tempArr.length == 2) {
    numberArr.push(tempArr);
    tempArr = [];
  }
}

const numbers = numberArr.map(number => {
  return parseInt(number.join(""));
});
```